# `add_route': path is required (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

This error happens when I try to restart my server with "rails s". It looks like a problem in `routes.rb`, which I've looked at, but don't see anything amiss and I haven't changed `routes.rb` for several commits. I can't find anything on this error anywhere. I could use a tip on where to look next for a cause. I'm sorry the following isn't formatted better:

```
 /Users/ianyoung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1543:in
 `add_route': path is required (ArgumentError) from
 /Users/ianyoung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1536:in
 `decomposed_match'from
 /Users/ianyoung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1517:in
 `block in match'
```

Running `rake routes` gives me a similar error:

```
 rake aborted! ArgumentError: path is required
 /Users/ianyoung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1543:in
 `add_route'
 /Users/ianyoung/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1536:in
 `decomposed_match'
```

To try to find the error in `routes.rb` I've removed parts/all of the content of that file except the opening block (below) and the error persists:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: Have you run rake routes?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I ran rake routes and it gives me a similar error (added above)

Comment: OK, either you've corrupted your environment or your routes.rb , I know you've mentioned you've not changed it, but can you try reverting it or posting it.

Comment: You really need to post your `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Remove good lines from rake routes until you've the smallest routes file that shows the problem, then add that to the question.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I've tried removing parts/all of the content of route.rb. Question updated, error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git diff` helped me figure it out. I'd extended class String in `config/initializers` with a string instance method called `blank?`. Rails didn't like that.

Comment: oh. wow. yeah that would explain why Rails thought the path was `blank?`